# ng-Click under Jquery Datatable responsive button

Tags: javascript, datatable, responsive, angularjs-ng-click

When I click on the button under Jquery Datatable responsive plus button the ng-click did not work.

[Under responsive button the html button ng-click do not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6DAZ.png)

[Can be seen on Live Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/smquocft/1/)

```
$scope.initTables = function(){ 
            var tbl =  $('#example').DataTable({ 
                responsive: true, 
            }); 
        }
```

Comment: Updated demo https://jsfiddle.net/smquocft/6/

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is completely broken. You are not using angular to point the initial values yet you want ng-click to solve it.

```
<th ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</th>
<button ng-click="alertME(name)"></button>
```

This would have given the correct value.

Comment: well the issue is when you see the button on screen ng-click works fine but when the button comes under responsive plus button then ng-click on the button don't work,

if you resize the output screen and make it smaller you will see green small round responsive button. when you click this green button then you will see the other columns and the html button and now the ng-click don't work on that button

Answer (score 0):

in your ng-click, you are using firstName, but you are not declaring that var anywhere.

Comment: it does not matter. In that case still ng-click triggers and shows alert message.
https://jsfiddle.net/smquocft/6/